# react native the [[DEFAULT]] firebaseapp is not initialized react-native-firebase

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to use react-native-firebase module with react native.

Error I am getting:

[image]

Steps I followed:

Step1: Created basic app

```
react-native init myFirebaseApp
```

Moved to project

```
cd myFirebaseApp
```

Installed module

```
npm install --save react-native-firebase
```

Step 2: Setup Firebase SDK (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/ios)

created firebase app and downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS

copied

> GoogleService-Info.plist

in project, then

```
pod init
```

Add these line to pod file

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

Installed dependencies

```
pod install
```

and finally linked library

```
react-native link
```

Someone can guide me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: what about AppDelegate.m file? https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/installation/ios#1.2.-Initialise-Firebase

Answer (score 5):

Modify your `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` files

In `AppDelegate.h` add this,

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

And in `AppDelegate.m` add `[FIRApp configure];`

```
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure]; // <=== Add this line

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

after the line

```
 "(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions "
```

in the AppDelegate.m file did the work for me.